# How to break up a viewmodel that's 450ish lines of code

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, refactoring

So I am still new to wpf/mvvm. I'm not using any framework, just a `VS wpf project`.

I have a main window view model, it has 5 properties, 3 commands, several private functions that get the data to populate the view with, 2 dialogs and their functions, and one delegate for an event handler.

I tried creating a `helper class` to handle the private functions, but those functions update properties that raise property changed events, so i had to add the same properties to the helper class. It felt strange to duplicate the properties in helper class from the view model.

Also, when I tried this, the property changed events were null because the data context of the view is set to the view model, not the helper. So my attempt failed.

The properties in the view model are for one component each-a `combo box`.

I don't really know how to break up the class anymore than I already have.

Should commands go in a separate file? If I move my private function into a helper class, how can I propagate a `OnPropertyChanged event` from the helper to the view model to the `xaml`?

Comment: Please put some code that could help us to understand your problem better and hel you.

Comment: A class with 450 lines does not sound like it seems to be broken up just because of size. As those lines are split between multiple methods.

Answer (score 1):

You could also work with partial Classes to separate different concerns.

You can use [foody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) to inject the property-Changed Code at compile-Time. 
With foody you can use [ImplementPropertyChanged]-Attributes, so there is no need for all the OnProperty-Changed stuff in your viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is that you should not have all that code in your MainWindowViewModel, it should only act as a container for your embedded views and handle global events and such. So try to modularize it as much as possible into multiple views (with correct naming which tells you the purpose of the view).

I am pretty certain that the dialogs can be extracted into own classes.

If you can't reduce the amount of methods by refactoring them into helper classes, maybe you still can reduce the size of the methods by refactoring as many commonly used code snippets as possible?

Answer (score 0):

One view can consist of many views. So, if one of your viewmodel is too big, you could consider creating new viewmodels and views which could be nested in the main viewmodel. That could be one way to do this.